# Propagate all arguments following nth argument in a zsh script

Tags: bash, zsh

If I have a script like

```
curl --socks5-hostname "127.0.0.1:${2-1080}" $1
```

I can do:

```
purl bing.com 1081
```

Meaning:

```
curl --socks5-hostname "127.0.0.1:1081" bing.com
```

Now I want to dynamically add new arguments like:

```
purl bing.com 1081 --connect-timeout 1
```

How would I be able to do it?

If I use

```
curl --socks5-hostname "127.0.0.1:${2-1080}" $1 "$@"
```

Then it would end up as:

```
curl --socks5-hostname "127.0.0.1:1081" bing.com bing.com 1081 --connect-timeout 1
```

This is not the desirable outcome...

I would like:

```
curl --socks5-hostname "127.0.0.1:1081" bing.com --connect-timeout 1
```

Comment: This would be a relatively straightforward use of `shift 2` to drop the host and the port from `$@` before using it, except for the fact that `$2` is optional. Should I assume that if there are two or more arguments, the port is always specified?

Comment: @chepner yes. But good point, can we check if the $2 is a number, if not then we assume the port is not specified and use `shift 1` instead of `shift 2`?

Comment: We could. I'll write that up (and another idea I had).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `shift` to "consume" the host and optional port, so that the remaining arguments can be passed on to `curl`.

```
host=${1:-Missing host}  # Exits if *no* arguments available.
shift

if [[ $1 =~ ^[0-9]+ ]]; then
    port=$1
    shift
else
    port=1080
fi

curl --sock5-hostname "127.0.0.1:$port" "$host" "$@"
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
curl --socks5-hostname "127.0.0.1:${2-1080}" $1 "{@:3}"
```

or

```
host=$1
port=${2:-1080}
shift 2
curl --socks5-hostname "127.0.0.1:$port" $host "$@"
```

Comment: This will give unexpected results with something like `purl bing.com --connect-timeout 1`; I asked the OP to clarify if that's a possible use-case.

Comment: `shift` also fails to shift anything if there is only one argument, so the `$host` would be duplicated.

Answer (score 3):

you can change your script into:

```
p=("$@")
curl --socks5-hostname "127.0.0.1:${p[1]-1080}" ${p[0]} "${p[@]:2}"
```

Comment: If you have array support, you almost certainly have the ability to slice `$@` itself without needing the array.